# Npgsql nuget installation failed

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, npgsql

I have .NET 4.6.1 and 4.5.1 and VS 2013

I am installing Npgsql 3.2.0 (PostgreSQL .NET provider).

It fails:
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NETStandard.Library (≥ 1.6.1)'.
'NETStandard.Library' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms'.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is likely VS2013, or rather your version of nuget. Can you make sure you have the latest version of the nuget extension and retry?

Comment: I am using the latest NuGet version for VS2012, and also have the same error message. Can I get some help for this?

Comment: thanks, yes, updated NuGet Package Manager, and it worked!! Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by installing the latest NuGet Package Manager, the latest version is 2.12.0.817

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca

Note that: Don't forget to restart VisualStudio.

Comment: thanks, yes, updated NuGet Package Manager, and it worked!! Much obliged.

Comment: @Acid Rider. Glad to know that help you. Would you please mark this as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who meet the same issue as yours.